# Type '{ flights: {}; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with passing array anyone can help? It is my first project with React and Typescript. An error is displayed on the SpaceRow component => Type '{ flights: {}; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Row, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from './components/Header/header';
import SpaceRow from'./components/containerRow/containerRow';

type MyProps ={
    flights: {};
}

interface MyState   {
    flights: {} ;
}

class App extends Component<MyProps,MyState>{



    constructor(props: MyState){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            flights: [
                {
                    id: 1 ,
                    date: 21/37/2137 ,
                nameMission: "Lot na marsa",
                description: 'Super lot'
                },
                {
                    id: 2 ,
                    date: 21/37/2137 ,
                    nameMission: "Lot na marsa",
                    description: 'Super lot'
                },
                {
                id: 3 ,
                date: 21/37/2137 ,
                nameMission: "Lot na marsa",
                description: 'Super lot'
            },
                {
                id: 4 ,
                date: 21/37/2137 ,
                nameMission: "Lot na marsa",
                description: 'Super lot'
                },
                {
                    id: 5 ,
                    date: 21/37/2137 ,
                    nameMission: "Lot na marsa",
                    description: 'Super lot'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        
        const spaceFlights = {
            flights: this.state.flights
        }
        
        return (
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                < Header />
                <SpaceRow  {...spaceFlights} />
            </Table>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

What is the cause of the problem and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOzYEW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.